# Deny access to root directory while allowing access to the DirectoryIndex for default page

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, directoryindex

I am trying to deny access to the root directory while allowing access to certain files (ending in .html and .js) and specifying a DirectoryIndex so requests for the directory will respond with a default page.

Checked these things already:

-Apache/2.2.14 can read its directory root.

-The DocumentRoot file exists.

-There are no other directory settings which configure the same directory

Here's one of the more explicit configs I tried.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName myserver.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/client

DirectoryIndex app.html

<Directory /var/www/client>
  AllowOverride None
  Options +Indexes
  Order Allow,Deny
  Deny from all

  <Files ~ "\.(js|html)$">
    Order Deny,Allow
    Allow from all
  </Files>

</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Gives a 403. I tried a couple of permutations, trying to be as explicit with directives as I knew how. I tried `allow from all` on the directory to prove there were no conflicting rules and the DirectoryIndex worked as expected (served app.html). With the above config I can get /app.html, just not have it served as the default for requests to "/".

This is what I ultimately did to get the desired effect.

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.0:80>
ServerName example.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/client

AliasMatch ^/$ /var/www/client/app.html

<Directory /var/www/client>
  AllowOverride None
  Order Allow,Deny
  Deny from all

  <Files ~ "\.(js|html)$">
    Order Deny,Allow
    Allow from all
  </Files>

</Directory>
<VirtualHost>
```

Is there a better way to achieve my goal? Does DirectoryIndex not work with ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using an AliasMatch is a good way to achieve what you want.

The reason why DirectoryIndex doesn't give you what you want is that the `Files` directive looks at the request made by the browser, and that request does not contain .html  or .js. The `AliasMatch` directive will ensure that the request gets rewritten before reaching the `Files` directive - but the DirectoryIndex doesn't happen in the proper context for it to be caught by the `Files` directive.